# Return first result within each result of an `IN` query in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I am running an IN query against my collection.
Here is my query structure:

```
 db.myCollection.find ( 
   { deviceId : { $in : [ "ABC", "XYZ" .. ] } 
 })
```

I know for a fact that each of these will return me multiple rows, but I am only interested in getting the first result of each.

I looked into the `$first` aggregation function, but could not see it a fit for my situation.

I could do a `findOne` query against each ID one at a time and combine the results in my client code written in Java. But there can be a lot of these IDs and I want to reduce the network round trip each time.

EDIT. Adding an example for more clarity.

Sample data in my collection:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "deviceSerial" : 1, "deviceId" : "ABC" }
{ "_id" : 2, "deviceSerial" : 2, "deviceId" : "XYZ" }
{ "_id" : 3, "deviceSerial" : 3, "deviceId" : "LMN" }
{ "_id" : 4, "deviceSerial" : 4, "deviceId" : "PQR" }
{ "_id" : 5, "deviceSerial" : 5, "deviceId" : "SDS" }
{ "_id" : 6, "deviceSerial" : 6, "deviceId" : "KLP" }
```

Now, if I do my query with `{ deviceId : { $in : [ "LMN", "XYZ" ] }`

Expected Output (sort does not matter):

```
{ "_id" : 2, "deviceSerial" : 2, "deviceId" : "XYZ" }  
{ "_id" : 3, "deviceSerial" : 3, "deviceId" : "LMN" }
```

Comment: How the actual output looks like? Using the provided sample and the query I get exactly the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the idea with $first is good. You need to filter the collection with $in and then eliminate duplicates. Following aggregation should work:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            deviceId: { $in: ["ABC", "XYZ"] }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$deviceId",
            doc: { "$first": "$$CURRENT" }
        }
    },    
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$doc" }
    }
])
```

doc will store first entire document for each group. On the last stage we need to promote this document to be a root and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) is able to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. This seems useful when my collection itself has an array, and I am doing a lookup on that. My case is different, I added some clarification in an EDIT now. Thanks.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood your question. Thanks for editing, it's always better to have sample documents and expected results. I've entirely edited my answer and now the solution should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Wow, I never would have come up with that. It works!